# Rails application Traceback error - spring and bootsnap gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails was working on my Mac before. It suddenly crashes and produces the following error irrespective of running rails s, rails db:migrate etc. I have the first two lines of the below text in my gemfile that is relevant to the gems

````
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'spring'

Traceback (most recent call last):
    32: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    31: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    30: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
    28: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/spring:10:in `require'
    26: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    24: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    22: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    21: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    20: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    19: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/bin/rails:4:in `require_relative'
    17: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/nnidadavolu/esas-s1-2021-assign-1/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    15: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:108:in `default_setup'
    13: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:67:in `setup'
    12: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:10:in `setup'
    11: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     9: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     8: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     7: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     5: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
     3: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     1: from /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle: stat() failed with errno=25 - /Users/nnidadavolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle```

I am not sure what or where the error is and how to fix it. Can somebody please explain and help?
````